# Heron's sequence

Tags: analysis

Given: $x_{n+1}$=$\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(x_{n}+ \dfrac{c}{x_{n}}\Bigr)$

I'm trying to prove the following:
$\;\Bigl[\dfrac{c}{x_{n+1}},x_{n+1}\Bigr]\subset\Bigl[\dfrac{c}{x_{n}},x_{n}\Bigr]$.

I have no idea how to prove it. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint and help me further.

Comment: How do you know the $\frac c{x_n}\le x_n$?

Answer (score 0):

This is false if $c>0$ and $\sqrt c >x_n>0.$ E.g. if $c=4$ and $x_n=1.$

If $c>0$ and $x_n>\sqrt c,$ observe that if $x_n>x_{n+1}> \sqrt c \,$ then $c/x_n<c/x_{n+1}<\sqrt c<x_{n+1}<x_n.$

So prove that if $x^2-c>0 $ then $0<((x+c/x)/2)^2-c <x^2-c.$